# How to reduce 'complexity too high' with || - or operator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cyclomatic-complexity

I've got a simple method that counts total lesson hours in the university schedule for additional modules in the department (students can attend many departments)

```
 def hours_total
    @hours_total = user.open_departments.each_with_object({}) do |department, h|
      h[department] = (sports_hours[department] || 0) +
                    (science_hours[department] || 0) +
                    (intership_sum[department] || 0) +
                    (art[department] || 0) -
                    ((obligatory_topics[department] || 0) +
                    (base[department] || 0))
    end
  end
```

How can I fix here `Cyclomatic complexity for hours_total is too high.`? I have no idea how to not repeat `|| 0` cause in some departments `sports_hours[department]` can be `nil` value

Comment: This code doesn't make sense. Where do all these variables, like `sports_hours`, come from? A good start would be to separate each of those conditionals into different methods.

Comment: In your case, I'd try `.to_i` instead of `|| 0`, you should refactor it further though.

Comment: sports_hours - other methods or query objects grouped by :department

Comment: @MarcinKołodziej thx that good idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step I'd take

```
def hours_total
  @hours_total = user.open_departments.each_with_object({}) do |department, h|
    positive = [sport_hours, science_hours, internship_sum, art].sum do |pos_h|
                 pos_h[department].to_i
               end

    negative = [obligatory_topics, base].sum do |neg_h|
                 neg_h[department].to_i
               end

    h[department] = positive - negative
  end
end
```

**Note:** if your hours can be float values, substitute `to_i` with `to_f`.

Now if you and your Rubocop are ok with that, I'd probably leave it. If any of you is unhappy, the `positive` and `negative` should be extracted to a method.

Comment: wouldn't `to_i` lead to an incorrect value? assuming time in hours then it could be `2.2 hours` and typecasting it to `integer` would result in incorrect value there.

Comment: ideally it should typecast only in case of `nil` value

Comment: Good point, when reading the original code I was under the impression that hours would be integers. I think `to_f` would be more generic, I'll add a note about that.

Comment: @Abhinay I'm not sure whether I'd be afraid of `to_f` or `to_i` here, I'd just make sure I'm using the correct method depending on the input. Might be habit though.